# Even after reinstalling data is not removed in ROOM database

Tags: android, android-room

I have developed a simple e-commerce app, even after reinstalling I am still getting the products saved in ROOM database. I have **clear data** and **cleared cache** and reinstalled the app still I am getting the datas back. I have deleted individual data manually in ROOM database and was not showing, after reinstalling I am getting the datas back. I have no idea how to delete permently from the ROOM database.

```
ext.room_version = "2.4.0"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Comment: Just a rough guess that it's due to [autobackup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup).

Comment: Hi Rohit, kindly check are you calling the insert method in onCreate, to store that data.

Answer (score 4):

In your AndroidManifest file, inside "application" tag do this:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```